# Error: cat: /boot/grub/video.lst: No such file or directory

Tags: grub2

I recently shifted from Windows (Windows7) to Ubuntu (10.10) 64 bit. After installation I performed the usual updates and I received a new kernel version (2.6.35-28-generic).

After that I read the post on the address mentioned below:

```
http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-users/2011-03/msg00932.html
```

to remove the additional kernel versions from the grub (& my system as I don't want to keep them).

Now when update the grub using the below mentioned shell command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I get the following result:

```
cat: /boot/grub/video.lst: No such file or directory
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Found FreeDOS on /dev/sda1
Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda4
done
```

Now I don't know what is the meaning of:

```
cat: /boot/grub/video.lst: No such file or directory
```

If it is an error, how can I fix it. Can anyone please guide me to fix it?.

Regards,
Fahad

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

/boot/grub/video.lst holds all the video modes that your machine is capable of. According to the GRUB documentation it is generated by grub-install. I've had no exerience with this problem before but maybe try to reinstall grub.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
echo vbe | sudo tee /boot/grub/video.lst
```

and then `update-grub` again!

Comment: works like a charm, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your /boot path is mounted read-write (rw) when you update grub or anything else in that path. It is often mounted (ro) after the installation for protection, but an update with fail if it is (ro).

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! If the problem was as you surmise, "No such file or directory" wouldn't be the error. This means that the file can't be found as it's not there or the location isn't mounted.